# ggplot2 change fill for color legend when fill also used in aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to control the fill for the color legend when fill is also used in the aesthetic in ggplot2?

Ex.

```
dat<-data.frame(id=as.character(1:4), var1=rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2), var2=rep(LETTERS[3:4], 2))
dat
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat)+
  geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1, fill=var2))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="black", "B"="grey"))+
  theme_light()
```

In this legend it is very hard to see the light grey border around the darker gray fill in the color legend.  I will admit it may not be a good practice to specify color and fill in the same plot as it can become difficult to understand which color means what and the colored borders around the filled objects can be hard to differentiate, but how would I do it if I wanted to?

[image: Here the background color for the color variable makes it difficult to see the grey outline]

By manually specifying fill in the plot, the fill color in the legend can be controlled when not also specifying fill.

```
ggplot(dat)+
  geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1), fill="white")+
  theme_light()
```

[image]
I thought there would be a way to control this using an argument in theme, but `theme(legend.background=element_rect())` controls the background of the whole legend (and rightly so)

```
ggplot(dat)+
  geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1, fill=var2))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="black", "B"="grey"))+
  theme_light()+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="blue"))
```

[image]

Also in theme, `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill="blue"))` only adds a thin blue line around the `var2` boxes in the legend, `legend.box` controls the arrangement of multiple legends ("horizontal" or "vertical"), and `theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(fill="blue"))` colors the background between the `var1` and `var2` legends.

I thought perhaps the legend was using the default value for NA for the fill, so I tried specifying this manually using `scale_color_discrete()`

```
ggplot(dat)+
  geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1, fill=var2))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="black", "B"="grey", 
                              na.translate=TRUE, na.value = "white"))+
  theme_light()
```

Looks the same as the first plot.

This seems like something that should be controlled by an argument in `theme()` or `scale_color_manual`, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For data-related aspects of the legend, `theme()` won't help you. Instead you need to use `guides` and override the fill for the color legend:

```
ggplot(dat)+
    geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1, fill=var2))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="black", "B"="grey"))+
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"))) +
    theme_light()
```

The general rule is that `theme()` only controls the overall look of the plot, not the data-dependent parts like scales (maybe instead of "data-dependent" it should be "the parts of the plot that vary based on data").

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! I completely forgot about `guides`.  Appreciate the explanation between `theme()` and `guide()` as well!

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing up this question and trying everything I could think of I did find a solution.  It does seem a little hacky and requires over plotting.

```
dat<-data.frame(id=as.character(1:4), var1=rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2), var2=rep(LETTERS[3:4], 2))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat)+
  geom_bar(aes(id, fill=var2))+
  geom_bar(aes(id, color=var1), alpha=0)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("A"="black", "B"="grey"))+
  theme_light()
```

Here by layering color bar chart with alpha=0 on top of the fill bar chart I can get the desired plot, but it feels a little like a corruption of `ggplot2`.  I hope a better answer exists.

[image]